# Add a column to a table with a default value equal to the value of an existing column in HBase through Apache Phoenix

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a table `products` with columns A, B.

I'd like to create a column C whose values are equal to B.

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD C DECIMAL(20,12);
UPDATE products SET C = B;
```

I'm getting some errors saying `UPDATE statistics`. Then I realised `UPDATE` is used for some other purpose. Then I tried it like below:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD C DECIMAL(20,12);
ALTER TABLE products  SET C = B;
```

I got `No rows affected` and C is still `null` for all the rows. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this statements to create a column and update it based on value from another one:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD C DECIMAL(20,12);
UPSERT INTO products(your_key, C) select your_key, B from products;
```